# Access to the CTRL-N auto-complete UI functionality

Tags: autocompletion

I have a list of strings in an external file.

I want to be able to access those strings, and perform the auto complete functionality on those, in the same way that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> works usually.

See the below image for what I mean by the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> functionality.

[image]

Is this, or something similar, possible in vim?

Comment: Without dabbling with options and whatnots, the simplest is to load that file into Vim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want:

['dictionary'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27dictionary%27)

For example, in my vimrc I have:

```
augroup vimrc
autocmd!
autocmd BufRead */debian/rules set dictionary+=~/.vim/dict/dh.txt
augroup END
```

dh.txt containing

```
dh_auto_build
dh_auto_clean
dh_auto_configure
dh_auto_install
dh_auto_test
dh_bugfiles
dh_builddeb
dh_clean
dh_compress
dh_dwz
dh_fixperms
dh_gencontrol
dh_icons
dh_install
dh_installcatalogs
dh_installchangelogs
dh_installcron
dh_installdeb
dh_installdebconf
dh_installdirs
dh_installdocs
dh_installemacsen
dh_installexamples
dh_installgsettings
dh_installifupdown
dh_installinfo
dh_installinit
dh_installinitramfs
dh_installlogcheck
dh_installlogrotate
dh_installman
dh_installmenu
dh_installmime
dh_installmodules
dh_installpam
dh_installppp
dh_installsystemd
dh_installsystemduser
dh_installudev
dh_installwm
dh_installxfonts
dh_link
dh_lintian
dh_listpackages
dh_makeshlibs
dh_md5sums
dh_missing
dh_movefiles
dh_perl
dh_prep
dh_shlibdeps
dh_strip
dh_systemd_enable
dh_systemd_start
dh_testdir
dh_testroot
dh_ucf
dh_update_autotools_config
dh_usrlocal
override_dh_auto_build
override_dh_auto_clean
override_dh_auto_configure
override_dh_auto_install
override_dh_auto_test
override_dh_bugfiles
override_dh_builddeb
override_dh_clean
override_dh_compress
override_dh_dwz
override_dh_fixperms
override_dh_gencontrol
override_dh_icons
override_dh_install
override_dh_installcatalogs
override_dh_installchangelogs
override_dh_installcron
override_dh_installdeb
override_dh_installdebconf
override_dh_installdirs
override_dh_installdocs
override_dh_installemacsen
override_dh_installexamples
override_dh_installgsettings
override_dh_installifupdown
override_dh_installinfo
override_dh_installinit
override_dh_installinitramfs
override_dh_installlogcheck
override_dh_installlogrotate
override_dh_installman
override_dh_installmenu
override_dh_installmime
override_dh_installmodules
override_dh_installpam
override_dh_installppp
override_dh_installsystemd
override_dh_installsystemduser
override_dh_installudev
override_dh_installwm
override_dh_installxfonts
override_dh_link
override_dh_lintian
override_dh_listpackages
override_dh_makeshlibs
override_dh_md5sums
override_dh_missing
override_dh_movefiles
override_dh_perl
override_dh_prep
override_dh_shlibdeps
override_dh_strip
override_dh_systemd_enable
override_dh_systemd_start
override_dh_testdir
override_dh_testroot
override_dh_ucf
override_dh_update_autotools_config
override_dh_usrlocal
```

Now I can complete those words, with [CTRL-X - CTRL-K](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-X_CTRL-K) (keyword-completion) when accessing a file in a `debian/rules` path.

Comment: Welcome vi.SE @dza :) Very nice answer, thanks.